# Ionic native File Transfer Plugin Compile error While Image Downloading to device

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I want to download an image and save it into the device

After getting File Transfer Plugin installed, when I run `ionic cordova run android`
I go this compile error:

```
platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\filetransfer\FileTransfer.java:49: error: package org.apac
he.cordova.file does not exist

import org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils;
```

The app work perfectly without the plugin installed.

My Only Requirement is to download image any plugin will work

Comment: The message appears to be clear, I think you just need to "import org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils;"  along with File Transfer Plugin

EDIT: File Transfer Plugin is deprecated 
https://cordova.apache.org/blog/2017/10/18/from-filetransfer-to-xhr2.html

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer

Cordova File Transfer seems to be deprecated and here is the post about it:

https://cordova.apache.org/blog/2017/10/18/from-filetransfer-to-xhr2.html

Here is the quick code : https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/index.html#download-a-binary-file-to-the-application-cache

Comment: any other plugin which might be helpfull